# Software version and SQL database - perfect approach

Tags: database, version-control, data-migration

Project code and project database usually grows together. Often some unit tests needs test databases and test database entries too.

What is the perfect way to sync database/contents and release/version management?

And does it support branching and revertation of code hand-in-hand with database data and db structure?

I currently commit my changes with comment SQL code for my svn trigger, but whats about the revertion of my code-changes?

Are there any perfect solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of dealing with this that I know is "Continuous Database Integration" - Google will lead you to tools and articles; [this](http://osherove.com/blog/2004/11/12/article-continuous-database-integration-by-peter-hancock.html) is a good start.